# How I change codes of a single txt file with a names list of csv in bash ubuntu?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a single txt file where there are several codes with its metadata. However, I have been seeing how to change those codes with their names.

For this I have a list in csv with two columns, where the codes are in one and the names are in the other. These are 79.

This is a draft of script I have made:

```sh
#Here, the variable "Nombre" are the values of column 1 and the variable "Codigo" are the values of column 2 of nombres_codigos.csv file
#
#Then, I have use command sed to replace values of "Codigo" with values of "Nombre" into read RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick file

#!/bin/bash
read nombres_codigos.csv
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
       Nombre="${line%;*}"
       Codigo="${line#*;}"
       echo "$Nombre"
       echo "$Codigo"

       read RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick
       while read -r line  || [ -n "$line" ]
       do
       if [ "$Nombre" == "$Codigo" ]
       then
                sed -i "s/$Nombre/$Codigo/g" RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick
                echo "reemplazar"
       else
                echo "no reemplazar"
       fi
done
```

p.s: nombres_codigos.csv is like:

Nombre;Codigo
EU528205_Floripondio_A56y7;EU528205_F
FJ710459_Floripondio_ABCD;FJ710459_F
EF514777_Floripondio123;EF514777_F
EU528999_Floripondio1;EU528999_F
...

```
My result is:
```

nombres.sh: line 2: read: `nombres_codigos.csv': not a valid identifier
nombres.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
But I hope from the file RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick:
```

((((((EU528205_F:1.0000005000176948E-6,FJ710459_F:1.0000005000176948E-6):1.0000005000176948E-6,EF514777_F:1.0000005000176948E-...

```
switch to this:
```

((((((EU528205_Floripondio_A56y7:1.0000005000176948E-6,FJ710459_Floripondio_ABCD:1.0000005000176948E-6):1.0000005000176948E-6,EF514777_Floripondio123:1.0000005000176948E-...

```
Could someone help me modifying this, please? Thanks very much.
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? what do you intend to achieve with the modification?

Comment: You'll want to paste your code into https://shellcheck.net to help with the syntax errors. Also read [How can I read a file line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update your question; in particular: provide a sample of the data from `nombres_codigos.csv`, the (wrong) output your script is generating, and the (correct) desired output

Comment: `for i in cat ...` is a dangerous *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`) instead, if you are going to use a loop, it's `while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do ... done < nombres_codigos.csv` (the `|| [ -n "$line" ]` part protects against files that fail to have a `'\n'` as the final character)  I found the example lines...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain what you are attempting to accomplish, but it appears you want to read each line from `nombres_codigos.csv` and then split the line on the semi-colon. Then you want to check if the two parts are the same (*which does not make sense with the* `sed` *expression that comes next*)

A directly, albeit cleaned up reformatting would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
  Nombre="${line%;*}"   ## separate using bash built-in parameter expansions
  Codigo="${line#*;}"
  
  echo "$Nombre"
  echo "$Codigo"
  
  if [ "$Nombre" == "$Codigo" ]
  then
    sed -i "s/$Nombre/$Codigo/g" RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick
    echo "reemplazar"
  else            
    echo "no reemplazar"
  fi
done < nombres_codigos.csv
```

If you separate `"$Nombre"` and `"$Codigo"` and then check if they are the SAME, then ... having `sed` replace `"$Nombre"` with `"$Codigo"` doesn't do anything at all. (It's like replacing `'A'` with `'A'`) Did you mean:

```
  if [ "$Nombre" != "$Codigo" ]
```

That would make what the script appears to do -- consistent. (e.g. change all instances of `"$Nombre"` with `"$Codigo"` in the file `RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick`) If that is the case, then just change the conditional and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, just this ---"change all instances of" $ Name "with" $ Code "in the file RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick" ---is what I'm looking to do.
Only the name and code values are in a csv file called codes_names.csv     .                                                                                     I just edited the post.

Comment: The changes above should get you close. You can replace the `< nombres_codigos.csv` with `< "$1"` and pass the name of the `.csv` file to read as an argument to your script. I don't have the `RAxML_bipartitions_newick.newick` file to test with, but I created a simple text file with lines containing the `$Nombre` values and running the script does replace them all with the corresponding `$Codigo` values.